# No event loop is runing on this thread

Tags: pyqt, qthread

I am creating a new thread to separate the UI interface from the data processing logic., but for reasons completely unfathomable to me, when I build and run my app , the app promptly crashes with the exception:

```
 File "capnp/lib/capnp.pyx", line 2150, in capnp.lib.capnp._DynamicCapabilityClient._send
capnp.lib.capnp.KjException: src/kj/async.c++:53: failed: expected loop != nullptr; No event loop is running on this thread.
stack: 0x7f9bd4774489 0x7f9bd477845d 0x7f9bd4c0aacc 0x7f9bd49a81cb 0x7f9bd49a8207 0x7f9bd49a8304 0x7f9bd54d0341 0x7f9bd4edb93e 0x7f9bd4edba96 0x7f9bd4ec305e 0x7f9bd4ec43e9 0x7f9bd4eb0651 0x7f9bd54b5ad8 0x7f9bd5485844 0x55b92dc620c5 0x55b92dd55107
```

I'm not sure what in the build system could cause this runtime error，here is my code ,My best guess is some kind of arcane linking quirk, but I have no idea what or how to fix it.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from cnc import Cnc

cnc = Cnc(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), "cnc"), "192.168.7.98")


class workthread(QThread):
def __init__(self):
    super(workthread, self).__init__()

def run(self):
    self.cnc_axis_names = {axis.id: axis.name.absolute for axis in cnc.axes}
    self.coors = {self.cnc_axis_names[id_]: coor for id_, coor in cnc.axes.coors().items()}
    data = list(self.coors.values())
    print(data)
    self.sleep(1)
    self.run()
    self.exic_()


if __name__ == '__main__':

  thread1 = workthread()
  thread1.start()
  app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this is welcome.

Comment: move `thread1 = workthread()
  thread1.start()` after `app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)`

Comment: I think there's no need to call self.run() in run method, because after calling start() method, it will call run() method.

Comment: I move thread1 = workthread() thread1.start() after app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv) and remove self.run(), the problem still exists， I think it may be a problem with capnp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `cnc` is, but my guess is that it uses Cap'n Proto RPC. Cap'n Proto RPC uses a single-threaded event loop concurrency model, so RPC objects originally created on one thread cannot be manipulated on another thread.

In your program, you are creating the `cnc` object at startup, in the main thread. You then create a new thread and try to access the object from there. This won't work. You need to construct and use the object on a single thread.

Comment: Thx,  That makes sense.